# Excel VBA API Request

Tags: excel, vba, api

So I don't have any experience coding whatsoever but I'm working on pulling some vehicle data from an government site with an API using VBA. so i don't have to manually adjust data in our vehicle list.

the code i wrote/stole:

```vb
Sub SendAPIRequest()

    Dim httpreq As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim response As String
    Dim headers As Collection
    Set headers = New Collection
    
    headers.Add "SVV-Authorization", "Apikey {1234}"
    
    
    Set httpreq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    url = "https://www.vegvesen.no/ws/no/vegvesen/kjoretoy/felles/datautlevering/enkeltoppslag/kjoretoydata?kjennemerke=AA91620" + kjennemerke
    
    With httpreq
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "SVV-Authorization", "1234}"
        .send
    End With
    
    response = httpreq.responseText
    Debug.Print response

End Sub
```

the request goes out but the with the following response: "status":403,"error":"Forbidden","path":"/enkeltoppslag/kjoretoydata"}
403 The API key does not exist in the database, has the status active and/or the user is blocked.

Additional info: REST service - Json response.
https://autosys-kjoretoy-api.atlas.vegvesen.no/api-ui/index-enkeltoppslag.html

key is legit so I'm sending the header out wrong?
Thanks in advance :)

copy & paste other code, etc.

Comment: If the key is 1234 the try `.setRequestHeader "SVV-Authorization", "Apikey 1234"`. Try with and without space after Apikey. The line `headers.Add "SVV-Authorization", "Apikey {1234}"` is not needed.

Comment: The URL has `+kjennemerke` at the end like it was a variable but it is not mentioned anywhere else or declared, could this be the issue?

Comment: `headers.Add "SVV-Authorization", "Apikey {1234}"` how is this connected to your request using `httpreq` ?   You should be adding that header to `httpreq`

Answer (score 0):

You can call the GET api like this:

```
GET https://www.vegvesen.no/ws/no/vegvesen/kjoretoy/felles/datautlevering/enkeltoppslag/kjoretoydata?kjennemerke=AA91620
```

Request Headers:

```
SVV-Authorization: Apikey 1234
```

So, you need to change the set of the request header to be like this:

```
.setRequestHeader "SVV-Authorization", "Apikey 1234"
```